# prev_entry and next_entry not outputting url_title_path

Tags: next-prev

I have a bit of a weird situation. I have an entry, and want to show next/previous buttons. I'm using Low Reorder, and this is my code:

```
<div class="grid__col bp1--full bp2--one-half">
    {exp:low_reorder:prev_entry
        set='projects'
        url_title='{segment_3}'
    }
        <a href="{url_title_path='work/projects'}" class="cta cta--full cta--prev"><span class="entypo chevron-thin-left"></span> {title}</a>
    {/exp:low_reorder:prev_entry}
</div>
<div class="grid__col bp1--full bp2--one-half">
    {exp:low_reorder:next_entry
        set='projects'
        url_title='{segment_3}'
    }
        <a href="{url_title_path='work/projects'}" class="cta cta--full cta--next">{title} <span class="entypo chevron-thin-right"></span></a>
    {/exp:low_reorder:next_entry}
</div>
```

When the template gets rendered, it doens't render the `{url_title_path=''}`, but just outputs it raw. This also happens with native `next_entry` and `prev_entry` (which I reckon Low Reorder delegates to). When i put in `/work/projects/{url_title}` that does work however. Anyone have a clue what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Low Reorder does *not* use the native prev/next entry methods, it uses its own. Also, `{url_title_path=""}` is *not* available as a variable in either [the native tags](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/entry_linking.html#variables) nor in the Low Reorder tags. It is specific to the channel:entries tag only.

Use this instead: `{path="work/projects/{url_title}"}`

Comment: Thanks. I still think it's pretty weird that this isn't available. Will open up a ticket with Ellislab to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try adding `parse="inward"` to the `{exp:low_reorder}` tag.